# Pivot column component in talend

Tags: database, pivot, pivot-table, talend

I have a requirement where i'm using tPivotToColumnDelimited component in talend. But this component generates the output in a FILE and not in database

Here i'm dealing with a lot of records where a FILE as a output is not recommended. So i need a way to write this output to DB and not to a file.

Any alternative would be appreciated.

If you want to how tPivotToColumnDelimited component works, refer this

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/13.43+tPivotToColumnsDelimited

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the third-party pivot components in [Talend Exchange](https://exchange.talend.com/) .
I suggest looking at tTurnRow and tpivotrow components.

I'm using that exact tPivotToColumnDelimited component to pivot approximately three million rows of data into about
four thousand rows.  After the Pivot to a file, I then read the file and do further processing of those pivoted rows. I find it to be fast enough in a batch-processing context.

Comment: tnx, its useful :) #Talend_Exchange

Comment: To install see this web page https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Installing+a+custom+component .   Thanks !